# prevent a method from returning null java

Tags: java, methods, null, return

I have a greetingLoop is called on by a switch case in main(), and if it returns null, user input is asked for once but doesnt do anything.  I am trying to avoid the greetingLoop() from returning a null, but as soon as I put the return variable userInput in an if statement, it isnt recognized by eclipse "this method must return a type of int."

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
public static int greetingLoop(){

     int userInput=0;
     try{
            System.out.println("Please enter the desired operation:");
            System.out.println("1.Insert, 2.Delete, 3.Edit, 4.Show, 5.List, 6.Volume, 7.Exit\n");
               userInput=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the desired  
               operation:"));
     }
    catch (NumberFormatException ne){
        System.out.println("your input " + userInput + " is not valid.  Please try again...\n");
     }  

     if(userInput >= 1 && <= 7){
        return userInput;
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not returning anything in the case where the if condition predicate was `false`

add `return userInput;` after the `}` of the `if` statement

at any rate, you cannot ever return `null` in your current method because your return type is primitive `int` and will always return an int value.

so, in this case if you add `return userInput;` as the last line in your method, it will return the initialized value `0`